# Stitching .pcd files with open3d recorded from different angles

Tags: point-clouds, open3d

I have a robot arm and I placed a Kinect camera to the end effector. Then I took several shots of an object from different angles, and recorded the transformation matrix from end robot base to the end effector. So basically I know where shots were taken from in global coordinates.

After the recording of photos, I created point clouds from the images, in PointCloud2 format. Then I converted them into .pcd format, so that it is compatible with open3d.

So to the problem, I have five pcd files in total, and I want to combine them together to get a meaningful data using open3d in Python. But I have never used it before and I couldn't see any tutorial, thread etc. regarding my problem.

To sum it up, I have five .pcd files, I know the position information in terms of where they are recorded from with the camera. I want to stitch them together using open3d in Python, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the implementation, as I have never worked with point clouds before. What I am asking is, do I have enough data for achieving my goal, and where can I find information about what to do next. Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: Since you have all pointcloud with the camera transformation in global coordinate system, just transform it using pcd.transform in open3d